# Rails 3.2.1 - jQuery tokenInput "no method" error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-tokeninput

I have followed the instruction in Railscast 258 tokenInput, as well as another [tutorial](http://behindtechlines.com/2011/12/182/), so I believe my rails app is set up properly.
The json script takes in queries normally as well.

In the generated HTML, I see the line

```
<script src="/assets/jquery.tokeninput.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

which looks like the jquery code is included properly.

But for reasons unknown, I'm getting the following error in my Javascript console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'tokenInput'

I also tried including in my `application.js`  the line `//= require jquery.tokeninput` but it didn't work.

Can anyone tell me why this is the case?  It'd be much appreciated!

Comment: Is `jquery` included before `jquery.tokeninput`?

Comment: yes, in the page source,  <script src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script> comes before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it, but running `bundle clean --force`, then running `bundle install` again.